# Writing a file in the rails console is not saving on exit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, csv, heroku

I have a rails app hosted on Heroku. Part of the app involves writing some data to a CSV and then renaming the file

The code is pretty simple and looks something like this

```
CSV.open(file_path, "a") do |csv|
    csv << some_data
end

File.rename(file_path, new_file_path)
```

When I run this code in the rails console, the file is renamed and when I read it, everything seems good. However, when I exit the console, the changes do not persist. When I re-enter the console, the file has reverted to its original state. Any idea what's going on? Thanks

Comment: try using `wb` instead

Comment: I don't think you can edit files in the way that you want to on a Heroku server. I don't understand how slugs work, but based on the `heroku run bash` example here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos, where the example shows the user deleting the `Procfile` with no ill effects, I'm not sure file changes have lasting effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku disk space is not meant for storage. It is specific to the instance. Any file operations should be done against an external service such as S3.

What is happening is an instance of your application is being started when you invoke the console. You are writing to the file system. Then when you exit the console the instance you were using vaporizes.

Then you are starting a new instance when you invoke the console again and your file is not there because it was written to another instance that no longer exists.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to do it.